# AWS Amplify Amplify.configure(awsconfig) error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, datastore, aws-amplify

I am using the amplify cli with my NextJs app. I feel like maybe I configured something wrong Im getting this error when trying to query data:

[WARN] 32:17.454 DataStore - Data won't be synchronized. No GraphQL endpoint configured. Did you forget `Amplify.configure(awsconfig)`?

But I do have an aws-exports.js file. BUT i do see it sais awsmobile , im not to sure what else I might be doing wrong.

aws-exports file:

```
const awsmobile = {
  aws_project_region: 'us-east-2',
  aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint:
    private,
  aws_appsync_region: 'us-east-2',
  aws_appsync_authenticationType: 'API_KEY',
  aws_appsync_apiKey:private,
}
```

Comment: it's a warning not an error

Answer (score 3):

As the warning suggests, you may want to check if `Amplify.configure(awsconfig)` is called to set up the library in your project.

For example, this is the example given in the official documentation.

```
// pages/index.js
import { AmplifyAuthenticator } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";
import { Amplify, API, Auth, withSSRContext } from "aws-amplify";
import Head from "next/head";
import awsExports from "../src/aws-exports";
import { createPost } from "../src/graphql/mutations";
import { listPosts } from "../src/graphql/queries";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";

Amplify.configure({ ...awsExports, ssr: true });
```

In your case, you may import `awsmobile` from `aws-exports.js` and call `Amplify.configure({...awsmobile, ssr: true});` in your app's entry point.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to add:

```
export default awsmobile;
```